# C++ return type question

Tags: c++, return-type

Is there any difference between these:

`struct Class* CreateClass();`

and:

`Class* CreateClass();`

It's just a factory function declaration. You can see that one has struct at the start and one doesn't. I've tried it both ways and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Which should I be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's from C; there's no difference* in C++.

*Okay, I lied, sorry. :P You can confuse yourself if you really want to, and make them be different if you use a `typedef` with the same name but a different underlying type, but normally they're not different. That's assuming `Class` is already declared, though... if `Class` is undeclared, the second one won't even compile.

That said, the convention is to do:

```
typedef struct Class { ... } Class;
```

so that it compiles the same way in both C and C++.

Comment: I think I understand. So in C if I want to use `Class* CreateClass();` then I have to use `typedef struct Class { ... } Class;`. But then in C++ if I want to use `Class* CreateClass();` then I only have to use `struct Class { ... };`. And then if I want it to be "backwards compatible" I should use the C version even when using C++.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make a difference as long as there's no function in scope with the same name `Class`. You shouldn't write a function with the same name as a class, and to follow common C++ style you should use just `Class *`.

[Edit: same correction as Mehrdad, no function *or typedef*]

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is no difference.  The use of "`struct`" there is just for backwards compatibility with C, in which declaring `struct foo { ... };` would declare a type named "`struct foo`", and "`foo`" would only be a valid type name if you then used `typedef struct foo foo`.